# How does Firebase Admin SDK Messaging deal with canonical_ids?

Tags: java, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-admin

I'm trying to migrate from a custom server implementation of the Firebase Messaging legacy HTTP API to the Firebase Admin SDK, and it looks great, but I don't see any mention of how to deal with `canonical_ids` in the documentation.

In the legacy HTTP API, if the `registration_id` was refreshed to to a new version and your server just didn't know about it yet for whatever reason, you'll get a successful JSON response, but it'll include a `canonical_ids` field and an updated `registration_id` you should use in place of the old one from then on.

How do I deal with this in the Firebase Admin SDK?